# codeigniter pagination page number issue

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, pagination

I'm trying to use Codeigniter pagination library , i want my pagination url to be like this :

mysite.com/codeigniter/controller/page/1

mysite.com/codeigniter/controller/page/2

mysite.com/codeigniter/controller/page/3

here is my controller :

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('model');
        $segment=$this->uri->segment(3);
        /* Pagination */
        $config['base_url']=base_url('controller/index');
        $config['total_rows']=$this->model->count_active_members()->num_rows;
        $config['per_page']=5;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        /* END Pagination */
        $result['members']=$this->model->get_active_members($segment);
        $this->load->view('view',$result);
    }
}
```

my model :

```
class Model extends CI_Model {
    public function get_active_members($segment) {
        $this->db->select('username,email,balance,ctimes,regdate');
        $this->db->limit(5,$segment);
        return $this->db->get_where('members',array('status'=>'active'));
    }

    public function count_active_members() {
        return $this->db->get_where('members',array('status'=>'active'));
    }   
}
```

it worked as i want but the problem that i have 9 rows in my db & it displays only 7

Comment: I've edited your post to indent it. Please consider indenting your code when posting examples here.  It makes it much easier for everyone to debug ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is the offset, try this instead :

```
$this->db->select('username,email,balance,ctimes,regdate');
$per_page = 5;
$segment = $segment > 0 ? (($segment - 1) * $per_page) : $segment;
$this->db->limit($per_page, $segment);
```

Comment: it worked but there remains a missed row in my db that's isn't displayed ?

Comment: One missed row, is it the last one or the first one ?

Comment: in the middle of my table ?

Comment: that's strange, first page start from [0 to 5], second [6, 10] and the third [11, 15], in which page the row must show ?

Comment: when i set per page to 5 a row disappear from [11,15] page & when i set it to 3 a row disappear from [6,10] page

Comment: Yes, my bad because I did add +1 to the segment value, I updated the answer `$segment = $segment > 0 ? (($segment - 1) * $per_page) : $segment;`